# when is select option value saved?

Tags: html

Let's say that a user selects thr third value from a select box and then submits a form and is redirected back to the same page.

It appears the browser keeps the third option selected. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not the browser cache at work, then the web application would likely have manipulated the HTML to decide which option to make `selected` so the markup looks like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>3</option>
</select>
```

Then the browser will always display the select with the third option selected.

I could be wrong but I think the selection is *maintained by the browser* only if you try to go back in the browser history.